# How do I solve $(x\cos y-y\sin y)dy+(x\sin y+y\cos y)dx=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x\cos y-y\sin y)dy+(x\sin y+y\cos y)dx=0$

ATTEMPT:

Rearranging the terms:

$(x\cos ydy+y\cos ydx) -y\sin ydy+x\sin ydx=0$

Dividing by $\cos x$ we get:

$(xdy+ydx)-y\tan ydy+x\tan ydx=0$

$ d(xy)-y\tan ydy+x\tan ydx=0$

But i am not able to simplify it further.

I also tried partial derivatives:

Let $(x\sin y+y\cos y)=M(x,y)$ and $(x\cos y-y\sin y)=N(x,y)$

This is not an exact differential equation as $\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} \ne \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}$

But $\frac{\frac{\partial M(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial N(x,y)}{\partial x}}{N(x,y)}=1$ which is independent of $ x, y$.

Can i use this result to solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $x\sin y+y\cos y=t$, then

$$\dfrac{dt}{dx}-(\sin y+\cos y\dfrac{dy}{dx})+ t =0$$

Now, put $z=\sin y$ then

$$\cos y\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{dz}{dx}.$$

Therefore

$$\dfrac{dt}{dx}-\dfrac{dz}{dx} + t - z =0$$

ó

$$\int \dfrac{d(t-z)}{t-z}=-\int dx.$$

The solution is

$$e^x(x\sin y +y\cos y -\sin y)=C$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(x\cos y-y\sin y)dy+(x\sin y+y\cos y)dx=0$$
$$xd\sin y+yd\cos y+(x\sin y+y\cos y)dx=0$$
$$x(d\sin y+\sin y dx)+y(d\cos y+\cos ydx)=0$$
$$xe^x(d\sin y+\sin y dx)+ye^x(d\cos y+\cos ydx)=0$$
$$xd(e^x\sin y)+yd(e^x\cos y)=0$$
$$xd(e^x\sin y)\color{red}{+(e^x\sin y)dx-(e^x\sin y)dx}+yd(e^x\cos y)=0$$
$$d(xe^x\sin y)-(e^x\sin y)dx+yd(e^x\cos y)=0$$
$$d(xe^x\sin y)-(e^x\sin y)dx+yd(e^x\cos y)\color{red}{+(e^x\cos y)dy-(e^x\cos y)dy}=0$$
$$d(xe^x\sin y)-(e^x\sin y)dx+d(ye^x\cos y)-(e^x\cos y)dy=0$$
$$d(xe^x\sin y)-d(e^x\sin y)+d(ye^x\cos y)=0$$
Integrate:
$$xe^x\sin y-e^x\sin y+ye^x\cos y=C$$
Finally:
$$e^x(x\sin y-\sin y+y\cos y)=C$$