# Solving $(x\cos y - y\sin y)dy - (x\sin y + y\cos y)dx =0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$(x\cos y - y\sin y)dy - (x\sin y + y\cos y)dx =0.$$

I know that this is not an exact differential equation. So I have tried various integrating factors that I know. How can I solve this using an exact differential equation? In fact, can it even be solved by this method? If not then can someone please tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Very similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414210/trigonometric-differential-equation-3

Comment: It looks to me like the method in that link should work well. Searching for an integrating factor in the conventional way appears pretty difficult because you need to solve the PDE $(x \cos(y) - y \sin(y)) \mu_x + \cos(y) \mu = -(x\sin(y) + y \cos(y)) \mu_y - (x \cos(y) + \cos(y) - y \sin(y)) \mu$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x\cos y-y\sin y)~dy-(x\sin y+y\cos y)~dx=0$

$(x\sin y+y\cos y)~dx=(x\cos y-y\sin y)~dy$

$(x+y\cot y)\dfrac{dx}{dy}=x\cot y-y$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=x+y\cot y$ ,

Then $x=u-y\cot y$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dy}+y\csc^2y-\cot y$

$\therefore u\left(\dfrac{du}{dy}+y\csc^2y-\cot y\right)=(u-y\cot y)\cot y-y$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}+(y\csc^2y-\cot y)u=u\cot y-y\cot^2y-y$

$u\dfrac{du}{dy}=(2\cot y-y\csc^2y)u-y\csc^2y$

Answer (score 0):

$$A(x,y)dx+B(x,y)dy$$
is exact if $$\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$$
The given differential is
$$- (x\sin y + y\cos y)dx +(x\cos y - y\sin y)dy $$
and
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}(-(x \sin y+y \cos y))=-x \cos y+y \sin y-\cos y$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x \cos y-y \sin y)=\cos y$$
$$\frac{\partial A}{\partial y}\ne\frac{\partial B}{\partial x}$$
The differential is **not** exact.

A method to solve it anyway can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential_equation).